# DatePicker Contact form 7

Tags: javascript, wordpress, plugins, contact-form-7, contact-form

I am trying to put a minimum date in my contact form 7, in the calendar it works normally, but if the user goes with the keyboard he can put an earlier date.
How can I make it so that the user can't go beyond the minimum date on the keyboard?

```
<label class="lbl" for="date">Dates <sup>   &#8727;</sup> : </label>
[date* date id:dates class:form-control date-format:dd/mm/yy first-day:1 placeholder ""]
<script>
var today = new Date();
today.setDate(today.getDate() - 0);
today = today.toISOString().split('T')[0];
document.getElementsByName("date")[0].setAttribute('min', today);
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a [`min:`](https://contactform7.com/date-field/) field?

Comment: Yes, I tried, but it didn't work :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This javascript could make the magic.

```
document.getElementsByName("date")[0].addEventListener("change", function(e){
    var min = this.getAttribute('min');
    
    if(this.value < min){
       this.value = min;
       /*
        you can also set a message to warn the user that the value has 
        changed because it has a min date. 
       */
    }
});
```

Comment: It didn't work, I can still put another date through the keyboard :/ but, thanks for the help

Comment: I got it, I put the today in this part  function(e){var min = this.getAttribute('min', today), but the mobile version crashes if I choose a lower date, for example, the alert appears but I can't change it to another date, can you tell me what it is?

Comment: So strange...  because i tested your code and it's all ok ...

Comment: Yes, I tested it on the desktop and it worked, but on iOS Safari it didn't work

Comment: In safari it doesn't let you change the value from keyboard... you can achieve it only using arrows

Comment: but how can I change this then? Would it have to be by another type of input? Thanks for your help